# modify the end of an image source from 's.jpg' to 'o.jpg' with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, url

My CMS has a plugin for pulling in facebook images with stories. I cannot change it.
In the source it creates the image URL ends in s.jpg but I would like to modify it so it ends in o.jpg in order to pull in the largest photo type

This is the code:

```
<div class="post_picture">
<img src="http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/534627_477964682254266_1412043521_s.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Is this possible? I would image you copy the source URL, modify the end from s.jpg to o.jpg and the replace the old URL w/ the new one.

**EDIT:**

Thanks everyone for your replies & solutions, below is another solution I found...

```
$('.div1>img').attr('src',function(i,e){
 return e.replace("s.jpg","o.jpg");
})
```

ex - http://jsfiddle.net/designaroni/4Da2a/

Comment: Does the plugin use iframes?

Comment: no it does not so there should be no issue of encapsulation

Comment: So just follow other users' advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function imgSrcOverwrite() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        loopImg, fbImgs = [];
    // Loop through each IMG, check if it's a facebook image & 
    // then replace _s.jpg with _o.jpg in the src attribute
    for ( var x=0; x<imgs.length; x++ ) {
        loopImg = imgs[x];
        if ( loopImg.src.indexOf('photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net') > -1 ) {
            loopImg.src = loopImg.src.replace('_s.jpg', '_o.jpg');
            fbImgs.push(loopImg);
        }
    }

    imgs = loopImg = null;
    // return array of fb images so you can do more stuff with them
    return fbImgs;
}

imgSrcOverwrite();
```

If you're using jQuery I'd replace the second line with

```
var imgs = $('.post_picture img'),
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/jmzk2/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate how thorough this is in that it checks the URL if it is a FB URL or not

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how it may be possible.

```
// get image dom element
var img = document.getElementById('imageId');

// update src
img.src = img.src.replace(/s.jpg/, 'o.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery,

Try to access the img tag by this -

```
var src = '';
$('.post_picture').find('img').each(function(){
src = $(this).attr('src').toString().replace('_s.jpg', '_o.jpg');
$(this).attr('src',src);
});
```

Comment: If the plug-in is opening this HTML in a secure iframe, you wont get access to the HTML inside it. I guess